# Second screen doesn't appear until initState is done

Tags: flutter, dart, statefulwidget

I have StatefulWidget which initState() triggers async onInit() function that triggers a top level function that returns list of items, then the onInit populates List of items.
Then I have Scaffold which body should return CircularProgressIndicator until items == null and then Column with the items.

The thing is that I tap button to navigate to the second screen it takes like 3-4 seconds until the screen appears and when it does, the list is populated. I'm pretty sure that the function doesn't let the screen to appear until it's done, but I have no idea why?

Why this behavior if it's supposed to navigate to the second screen then start initState and show loading indicator until the func is done?

Can anyone help me with this, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case because the function I trigger on initState() makes some heavy calculations and because Dart is single thread language and because CPU is separated from I/O it starts the calculations and until the function is done it doesn't build the widget.

Because of this I opted to use an Isolate!

Answer (score 0):

Are you testing this on iOS?
Flutter has had an issue with the Shader Caching on the Metal engine, ever since Apple deprecated OpenGL.

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/32170

Second are you using a **FutureBuilder**?
Next, for all operations where you need to load information from some datasource, and you have to get the user to wait for it, please make sure to use a **FutureBuilder** widget.
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html
Always use a future builder to avoid any delays, and anything that you can make asynchronous, do so.
Below is a link to some performance tips from the flutter team:
https://flutter.dev/docs/perf/rendering/best-practices

I have written a small implementation for you, to demonstrate how to implement what you are looking for.

```
Future<List<String>> loadItemsFromSource;
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
    
  loadItemsFromSource = doSomeLogic();
  }

Future<List<String>> doSomeLogic(){

   //Read the results from the top level function
   //then return the results here

   return topLevelFunction(); //returns a list of Strings
}
    
    
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return FutureBuilder<List<String>>(
          future: loadItemsFromSource,
          builder: (context, state) {
            if (state.connectionState == ConnectionState.active ||
               state.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                 return Center(
                         child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                                backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                                valueColor: new AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color> 
                                (Colors.orange),
                       ));
                  } else {

    //return a ListView of your results
            return new ListView.builder(
                  itemBuilder: (item, index) {
                    return Container(child: Text(state.data[index]));
                  },
                  itemCount: state.data.length);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Yes, I’m testing. It on iOS. Thanks for the answer I’ll take a look in an hour or so and let you know if it works fine.

Comment: if this solves for you, please make sure to upvote. This will help me, help more people. Thanks

Comment: Sorry but this doesn't work. First I tried it on Android and it's the same or even worse. Then just rewrited the code to use FutureBuilder and it does the same the screen appears after the top level function is done.

Comment: In that case you will need to use a RestartableTimer class, available in the dart:async package.

Comment: This timer will run for lets say 2 seconds, and it will enable a boolean property to be true. This boolean property make sure to add it into the if condition of the futureBuilder. Once the timer is finished then the property is set to true, and the future builder is allowed to render the rest of the ui

Comment: Another thing, make sure that you move any cpu intensive work into an isolate. But don't do any plugin work in that, because it will fail

Comment: That’s what I did, I put it on isolate, now rewriting the business logic.

Comment: can you please paste the code, which you wrote on this thread. Just change it around a little, as to not expose any intellectual property. It's only the concept I want to investigate.
What I'm trying to say in the previous comments, is that you have to force the app to run the navigation first, then run the heavy work. The user needs to be given the illusion as if they are navigating to a loading screen, then their data loads, while they wait a couple of seconds.

Comment: When you do the heavy work though (in the isolate), while the loader is running, then the UI (loader) should not have any skipped frames.

Comment: Not home right now, but this is what I have at the moment: Navigate to second screen, run the isolate, on message populate getx observable list and this works fine until now. Next thing should be to implement the GetBuilder. Previously I’ve tried to use the ever worker but it doesn’t trigger, despite the list is populated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227534/discussion-between-i6x86-and-dan-gerchcovich).